# Getting syslog.Writer undefined

Tags: go

I have created the custom type with like following.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
     "log"
     "log/syslog"
     "strconv"
     "time"
)

type MyLogger struct {
     w       *syslog.Writer
     LogName string
}
```

And I'm getting error syslog.writer undefined. Even I tried the same in golang play ground and its giving same error.

https://play.golang.org/p/2unuwHBoBE

Comment: Are u in windiws env? This package is not implemented on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I am in windows environment but see the playground one there also I'm getting error and they are not using windows environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://blog.golang.org/playground,

> To isolate user programs from Google's infrastructure, the back end runs them under Native Client (or "NaCl")

And from the https://golang.org/pkg/log/syslog/

> This package is not implemented on Windows. As the syslog package is frozen, Windows users are encouraged to use a package outside of the standard library. For background, see https://golang.org/issue/1108.
>
> This package is not implemented on Plan 9.
>
> This package is not implemented on NaCl (Native Client).

You are using Windows, and Go Playground is using NaCl, which both syslog is not implemented.